# Iterating through user profiles on Windows 7 cscript.exe

Tags: windows, windows-7-x64, wsh

i'm trying to iterate through users profiles and log each profile on a system.

`for /d %%X in (C:\Users\*) do (`

`echo %username% >> C:\%computername%.log`

`)`

The problem i'm having is i have to run this cmd with elevated privileges.  So since it's being run as admin, the output is just Admin

i've tried echo `%username%,%cd%,%userprofile%` and i can't get the output of the current path... i was hoping %cd% worked because i was thinking that during the loop it's going into the path... but ur still the admin account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking you may have wanted:

```
for /d %%X in  (C:\Users\*) do (
    echo %%X >> C:\%computername%.log
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the following powershell script:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -ComputerName . -ErrorAction Stop  | where-object { $_.localAccount -eq "true" -and $_.Disabled -eq "false" -and $_.Name -cnotcontains "ASPNET"}
```

Or using cscript:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
If Not IsObject(objWMIService) Or IsNull(objWMIService) Then
    wscript.echo "Not an Object"
    wscript.quit
End If

Set usersItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_UserAccount " _
    & "WHERE localAccount=true and disabled=false",,48)
If Not IsObject(colItems) Or IsNull(colItems) Then
    wscript.echo "Not an Object"
    wscript.quit
End If
```